# Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition

Tags: neural-network, pattern-recognition

Hey guys, 
 Am wondering if anybody can help me with a starting point for the design of a Neural Network system that can recognize visual patterns, e.g. checked, and strippes. I have knowledge of the theory, but little practical knowledge. And net searches are give me an information overload. Can anybody recommend a good book or tutorial that is more focus on the practical side. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you only trying to recognize patterns such as checkerboards and stripes? Do you have to use a neural network system?

Basically, you want to define a bunch of simple features on the board and use them as input to the learning system. It can often be easier to define a lot of binary features and feed them into a single-layer network (what can become essentially linear regression).

Look at how neural networks were used for learning to play backgammon (http://www.research.ibm.com/massive/tdl.html), as this will help give you a sense of the types of features that make learning with a neural network work well.

Comment: Am trying to build a neural network sys, that can from a picture, identify patterns such as stripes, checked, polka dots. And it is for school assignment. I already said i was going to use neural networks (but it is not 'set in stone', so I can change it as an last alternative)

Comment: Another question... is neural networks the best thing for this kind of task? or is there some other field I should check out?

Comment: A neural network can be engineered to work, but there may be simpler techniques that work as well. (These could also be inputs to your neural network). You might want to check out the Hough transform (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

Comment: If you have an input for every pixel, and lots of training images, my guess is that a neural network could learn your three patterns pretty easily. (You'd have three outputs, one for each of the patterns.)

Comment: as a matter of opinion, what method would you use? <br/> I hope to have about 10 patterns. varying from stripes to plaid.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to learn. If you want to learn more about neural networks, try that and see what you can get working. I'd really recommend trying 2-3 methods to understand how each works and what is easy/hard about each approach.

Comment: I'll try the neural method first. But can you name some of other methods that can be used, so i can have a starting point for when i finish the neural network method.

Comment: A second approach would be to use image processing algorithms, such as the Hough transform, which can recognize lines and circles. The other approaches suggested by @Throwback1986 may be useful. You could essentially build a decision tree: check for circles, and if you find them classify as dots. Then check for lines for classifying stripes, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, you probably want to reduce your image a set of features.  A corner detector (perhaps the [Harris method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection)) could be used to determine features in the checkerboard pattern.  Likewise, an edge detector (perhaps [Canny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)) could be used in the stripes case.  As mentioned above, the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) is a good line detection method.

MATLAB's image processing toolbox contains these methods, so you might try those for rapid prototyping.  OpenCV is an open-source computer vision library that also provides these tools (and many others).

Comment: I just downloaded OpenCV, and i can programing in python, and not C or C++. And am trying to run one of the sample programs to get a feel of it. But it tells me 'no cv module found'. Is there an installation guide any where that can help, cause am not finding any on the website.

Comment: This one worked for me: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide.  However, I'm generally work in C/C++, so I haven't yet tried it in python.